# Incluir gráficos en Reporte PDF

Tags: javascript, django, pdf, highcharts, xhtml2pdf

tengo una página en html que usa JS Highcharts, imágenes, tablas, etc. y estaba buscando exportar todo a un reporte PDF (con tablas, imágenes, etc.). El problema es que dado que Highcharts (y otros gráficos JS) se renderiza en el navegador, no aparece en el pdf generado. Probé JSPdf y PhantomJS pero con esos generadores de "capturas de pantalla" estoy perdiendo todo el estilo y el formato que he creado con xhtml2pdf (portada y contraportada, marcas de agua, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Ahí pude resolverlo. Les comparto por si a alguno le sirve:
.- Tengo el Template con los gráficos en HighchartsJS.
.- Levanto el canvas del gráfico y lo guardo en un input oculto del formulario :

```
(function (H) {
    H.Chart.prototype.createCanvas = function (divId) {
        var svg = this.getSVG(),
            width = parseInt(svg.match(/width="([0-9]+)"/)[1]),
            height = parseInt(svg.match(/height="([0-9]+)"/)[1]),
            canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
        if (canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d')) {
            canvg(canvas, svg);
            return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        }
        else {
            alert("Your browser doesn't support this feature, please use a modern browser");
            return false;
        }
    }
}(Highcharts));
var imageData = $("#ausentismo_tot").highcharts().createCanvas();  
$('#aus_tot_image').val(imageData); //Hidden Input del Formulario
```

.- Viaja con el submit del Form y lo proceso en el views.py:

```
aus_tot_image = request.POST['aus_tot_image']
```

.- Imprimo el pdf y en el template del pdf (procesado con xhtml2pdf) pongo en

```
<img src="{{ aus_inc_image }}" >
```